# pip install wheel package using Chef on AWS EC2 instance ( CentOS 6.5 )

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, pip, chef-infra

Environment : CentOS 6.5, Python 2.7 (Anaconda), Chef (10.26)

- I need to bootstrap a machine which has only root user.
  In the chef runlist first thing is to create ec2-user and later run all recipes which includes installing [Anaconda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_%28Python_distribution%29)
- My requirement is to install Python "wheel" package as ec2-user using `pip`. I have tried the below snippet in my recipe:

  ```
  python_pip "wheel" do
    user "ec2-user"
    group "ec2-user"
    action :install
  end
  ```

The above fails saying this

> The temporary folder for building (/tmp/pip-build-root) is not owned by your user!

Note that, I run the chef-client as root as my use case demands that. Not sure if it can be done otherwise.

- I also tried the following snippet as a work around but which did not succeed:

  ```
  execute "installing wheel" do
    command <<-EOH
    su - ec2-user
    pip install wheel
    EOH
  end
  ```

By this it installs in default python as a root user.

Can anyone please help me with this issue? I need to install wheels as ec2-user using Chef.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Python packages as a user with write access to the Python installation. For system-wide installs (which is the case here since you aren't specifying a venv) this is almost certainly going to be root. Why do you think you want to install as a non-root user?

To add to that, the `wheel` package is only needed to build wheel archives not to install them. Wheels will be used automatically by pip if they are available from PyPI or via a specified wheel folder.

Basically you don't need to be doing any part of this.

Comment: we need to create wheels for some packages. Do you mean without doing pip install wheel, we can still use it. Because I had to do pip install wheel on some other machine where I needed wheel to build it.

Comment: Generally you would build the wheels either on a workstation or a CI server, not as part of a bootstrap. That said, just remove the `user` line and it should install correctly.